# How to append to the PATH variable in Visual studio 2013

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, quantitative-finance, quantlib

I want to append a value to my PATH environment variable. I thought this should be easy but its not working in the Developer Command Prompt for VS2013. I have tried the following commands:

```
set PATH = C:\temp;%PATH% //No quotes
set "PATH = C:\temp;%PATH%" //Quotes around everything
set PATH = "C:\temp;%PATH%" //Quotes only around the value
set PATH = "C:\temp;"%PATH% //Quotes around the new value to be appended
```

I have looked online and everyone seems to suggest the first or the second option above but when I

```
echo %PATH%
```

I dont see C:\temp in the PATH variable.

Any help is appreciated. I am on windows 7 and I work in python but needed to install quantslib. So, I have to go through visual studio.

Comment: Pretty unclear what "my command prompt" might have to do with VS2013.  You are only changing the PATH for the command session you are running.  It does not affect the environment of any other running processes and changes are lost when you close the console.  If it is supposed to last then you must change the system environment and restart processes so they use the changes.

Comment: I was just trying to provide a detailed picture of what I was trying to do. So, are you saying that when I do echo %PATH% in the command session I am running, my changes will never show up even though the PATH variable has been modified for the current command session?

Comment: there should be no spaces around `=`, or you'll create a variable called `"PATH "` (yes with a trailing space in name) and with a value `" C:\temp;%PATH%"` (with a space in front)

Comment: Thank you. Spacing was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The environment block is captured when a process starts, which means that Visual Studio won't see the updated path unless you restart it.

Editing the path from the command prompt is possible, but this is the easier way to modify an environment variable:

1. Right Click on "My Computer"
2. Click on "Properties"
3. In the Left-Hand Column, Select "Advanced system settings"
   [image: Advanced System Settings]
4. Click on the "Environment Variables..." button.
   [image]
5. Under "System variables" select the "Path" variable, then click "Edit...".
   [image]
6. Edit the path to your heart's content, then click "OK"
   [image]
7. Press "OK" on the two open dialogs. If any program that's currently running needs this path, you'll have to restart that program. If you want to be really sure that everyone has the new PATH values, reboot the computer.